# Animate Angular-flash Alerts

Tags: angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

Using the package, [Angular-flash](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/angular-flash/) and having issues adding custom animations to the showing and hiding of an alert.

From the docs

> If you want to use animations, include ngAnimate module. You can then
>   use regular Angular animation technique for applying your own
>   transitions.

```
.alert {...}
.alert.ng-enter, .alert.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {...}
.alert.ng-leave, .alert.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {...}
```

I feel like I've tried all possible combinations but struggle to get the in . out effects.

**My HTML**

```
    <flash-message>
        <div>{{ flash.text }}</div>
    </flash-message>

    <button ng-click="showFlash()">PRESS ME</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.showFlash = function() {
    var message = '<strong>Hello!</strong> ';
    var id = Flash.create('info', message, 4000, false);
};
```

Just to test my CSS animation is working I just added an animation to the alert class. This provides the show animation only.

```
.alert {
    animation: 1.5s zoomIn ease;
}
```

I need to be able to attach it to the "Alert Show Event" and then attach a zoom out to the "Alert Hide Event", allowing a specific show and hide effect.

I've tried these in multiple combinations but struggle to find what class to associate with the show / hide animations.

```
.alertIn, 
.alertOut
.alert.ng-hide-add-active
.alert.ng-hide-remove-active
```

Thanks

Comment: Anyone knows how to animate it?

Comment: @Soundwave I now use this - much better I think https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification

Answer (score 0):

I developed a flash message package and uploaded it in npmjs.com, i think the package will help you,

```
Package Name: Flash-Text
author: VamshiDureddy
```

Comment: You should perhaps offer an explanation and/or sample code that demonstrates how your package will work in the OP's case.

Comment: In npmjs, under the section of implementation, I explained how to use this package.
Please follow this link:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/flash-text